# Parsing custom protocol and adding to QuickFIX Server for send to clients

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I built a QuickFIX server. I'm parsing data provider custom protocol. I want to convert my protocol to FIX messages and send to all clients. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

First of all where is your QuickFIX server ? Is it like you receive your message from your data provider and then pass it on to the FIX engine ? In that case parse the data provider's message into a FIX message of the version your QuickFIX is configured for. Your QuickFIX engine can read the message and convert the message into a FIX formatted message.

This works both way. Use the QuickFIX engine to read the custom data and convert it into a FIX message to use further. It may involve an overlap of your data provider's API and QuickFIX.

Comment: **"> Is it like you receive your message from your data provider and then pass it on to the FIX engine ?"**  
Yes, I want to pass converted messages to FIX engine and send all clients.
**"> Your QuickFIX engine can read the message and convert the message into a FIX formatted message."**
This is my question. QuickFIX how can read my FIX formatted (or converted to QuickFIX objects) messages. I want to write an adapter between data provider and QuickFIX server simply. Thanks

Comment: There are sample application in example directory in Quickfix. Did you check that, they have examples of creating FIX messages. Refer here http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/

Comment: as I said, I can convert and create to FIX messages already. I can't send to FIX server for sending to FIX server's clients. **I want to write an adapter between data provider and QuickFIX server simply.**  I already checked examples and read a lot articles. Thanks

Comment: You never said you were able to create FIX messages. Clear something for me. Where are you creating your FIX messages and how ? Where is the data you get stored, if it is, or you convert it to  FIX, if so where ? And what is your Quickfix engine doing , is it an initiator or an acceptor ? And there is an example of an acceptor in the Quickfix library, did you see that ?

Comment: I think I said my first comment. My QuickFIX Server running as acceptor. Because clients are connecting it. Only how to configure acceptor described in example.

Answer (score 1):

The more you clarify the more confusing this question gets so I will attempt to clarify (I'm having the same problems understanding as DC is)

My understanding from what you've said so far is that clients connect to your QuickFIX server(known as a FIX acceptor) and, when you recieve data from the provider API you translate it into FIX and send it to the connected clients. Is this correct?

My guess is that the clients are actually connecting via the other, custom protocol and you need to convert their messages to FIX but I'm going to keep going with the way round you are saying.

Therefore, is what you need help with converting the data that is provided by the other protocol into the correct FIX tags to be sent out to the clients connecting via FIX to your server?

Comment: **My understanding from what you've said so far is that clients connect to your QuickFIX server(known as a FIX acceptor) and, when you recieve data from the provider API you translate it into FIX and send it to the connected clients. Is this correct?**  
Yes this is true.  
**My guess is that the clients are actually connecting via the other, custom protocol**  
Yes, this is true.  
In this point, I converted my protocol to messages, but I can't add QuickFIX server's global message cache for sending to clients.

Comment: you don't add to a message cache you just send to the target counterparty in FIX